# How can I infer a recursive TypeScript Type?

Tags: typescript, recursion

I am currently building a TypeScript collection class for my application but have struggled to find a solution in order to infer recursive calls.

**arrays.ts**

```
export interface Arrayable<T> {
    toArray(): Array<T>;
}

export function isArrayable<T>(object: any): object is Arrayable<T> {
     return typeof object === "object" && 'toArray' in object;
}
```

**collection.ts**

```
import { Arrayable, isArrayable } from "./arrays";

export class Collection<T> implements Arrayable<T> {
    private elements: Array<T>;

    constructor(elements?: Array<T> | Arrayable<T>) {
        if (typeof elements === "undefined") return;

        this.elements = this.getElementsArray(elements);
    }

    chunk(size: number): Collection<Collection<T>> {
        let chunked = [];

        for (let i = 0, len = this.elements.length; i < len; i += size)
            chunked.push(new Collection(this.elements.slice(i, i + size)));

        return new Collection(chunked);
    }

    toArray(): any[] {
        return this.elements.map((value: T) => {
            if (isArrayable(value))
                return value.toArray();

            return value;
        });
    }

    private getElementsArray(elements: Array<T> | Arrayable<T>): Array<T> {
        if (Array.isArray(elements)) {
            return elements;
        } else if (isArrayable(elements)) {
            return elements.toArray();
        }
    }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
let col = new Collection([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
    .chunk(3)
    .toArray();
```

Here the value of col is typed as any[] which is my current work around.

Is there any way to get this to infer number[][]?
I basically want toArray to recursively collapse the collection as required.

Comment: No because the implementation of `toArray()` in `Collection<T>` violates `Arrayable<T>` interface. It should return an `Array<T>`, but it fact in returns an array whose elements are either `T` or whatever type is returned by `value.toArray()`, and the latter is not specified (so it's inferred as `{}[]`, because generic parameter for `isArrayable` call inside `toArray` is inferred as `{}`)

Comment: Is there a way to use a second generic type, `TA` to infer the deep type. For example a `Collection<number>.toArray()` should be `number[]`. While `Collection<Collection<number>>.toArray()` should be `number[][]`. I could pass in the second generic type inside the chunk function.